# jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips Arabic Support

Tags: css, arabic, jquery-ui-slider-pips

Does jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips Has Arabic Support, because if we just make the direction from right to left it will select the wrong item when we click on the drag icon of the slide?
And how can  it be configured to support Arabic or any right to left language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codifier; the plugin does not have any notion of language/text. It simply displays the slider values (by default; numbers) in a linear fashion. But the order is left>right.

If you supply a `labels` option to the plugin it will accept an array of strings; http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#example-hanzi-labels so you may provide your Arabic values in reverse order which could achieve the result you desire.

```
var numerals = ["٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩","١٠"];
```

You may see an example here; http://jsfiddle.net/1utnokeg/1/

Answer (score 1):

you must use utf8 when you need your code supported arabic:
i think this can helpful

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: thank you for the helpful tip of the meta support for Arabic. but still need a tweak for the slider.